# Require export default module in test files

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I am trying to require a module in my test files, but can't figure out how to do it when I export it as a default module. I have the following code:

**server.ts**

```
import { MyClass } from './myClass';

/* Other code here */

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Started');
});

export default server;
```

This builds perfectly fine using webpack. I export the server because I want to be able to test it in my spec files. I tried doing this in my test file (using mocha):

**testFile.ts**

```
describe('Express Server', () => {
    let server: any;

    beforeEach(() => {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve('./server.ts')];
        server = require('./server.ts');
    });

    afterEach((done: any) => {
        server.close(done);
    });

    it('sample test', (done: any) => {
        done();
    });
});
```

Of course, the above is not testing anything. But it doesn't matter since it throws an error in the before each: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

How can I require my server module? I need to be able to reset the require before each test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had to change the module defined in `tsconfig.json`. I changed it to "commonjs" from "es2015" and the error posted in the question went away. In addition, I also had to change how I retrieved the server as posted below (added `.default` after the require).

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs", // Had to change the value for this
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./dist",
        "./node_modules"
    ]
}
```

**testFile.ts**

```
describe('Express Server', () => {
    let server: any;

    beforeEach(() => {
        delete require.cache[require.resolve('./server.ts')];

        // Had to change this line to have ".default" at the end
        server = require('./server.ts').default;
    });

    afterEach((done: any) => {
        server.close(done);
    });

    it('sample test', (done: any) => {
        done();
    });
});
```

I'm not fully educated on the differences between "es2015" and "commonjs", so if someone knows, please share. Using the above changes, I was able to run the following command:

```
nyc ts-mocha -p tsconfig.json --reporter mocha-multi-reporters --reporter-options configFile=test/config/mocha-config.json test/**/*.test.ts --exit
```

and it pulled in the server and all my tests pass without any errors. Thank you [Freez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332533/freez) for mentioning the test environment might not be reading the typescript correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your test environment seems to not support TypeScript files.

Try to run the mocha command using `ts-node`

```
mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/test.ts
```

source: https://journal.artfuldev.com/write-tests-for-typescript-projects-with-mocha-and-chai-in-typescript-86e053bdb2b6

Comment: They do. I have other test files written in typescript and they work fine. This is the command I run: `nyc ts-mocha -p tsconfig.json --reporter mocha-multi-reporters --reporter-options configFile=test/config/mocha-config.json test/**/*.test.ts --exit`

Comment: I did try adding `-r ts-node/register` but I get the same error.

Comment: What happen if you don't `delete require.cache[require.resolve('./server.ts')]`, same error?

Comment: Yep, the same error was coming up. I found the solution thanks to your insight (posted the answer). Thank you!